# Having trouble using responsive feature of Superfish

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

I am using the [Superfish](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish) module for Drupal 7.x, and the menu itself works as advertised. However, no matter what configuration options I try, I cannot get the main menu to change into a select menu when at smaller screen sizes. It just attempts to render the original menu (which, of course, becomes a mess at smartphone size).  I'm not even sure where to start looking for a problem.  Any clues would be appreciated!

Comment: What version of the module are you using? If I had to guess, I would say you need 7.x-1.x-dev from July, 2014 and not 7.x-1.9 from over 2 years ago.

Comment: I am using 7.x-1.9.  I'll have to give the dev version a shot.

Comment: Yep, I tried the dev version--it works!  Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Great, glad that helped!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem a while ago, and wound up writing some javascript/css to convert a multi-level superfish menu into a windowshade-style menu. It wasn't very elegant, though, and I later found the [Responsive Menus](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_menus) module - it was very easy to set up, from what I remember, and worked with Superfish right out of the box. It also provides several styles of mobile navigation -- though not a select menu, if that's specifically what you want.

Comment: I've used the Responsive Menus module successfully in the past, but not with Superfish. I tried it, and still no result.  The whole thing makes me feel like an idiot...maybe I'm missing something incredibly obvious?